# CSS Border wont show

Tags: html, css, border

So I have a border that wont appear. It's supposed to create a dashed block, but it doesn't.

Heres what I have set up in the CSS:

```
#coupon {
   border: 5px dashed black;
   float: left;
   width: 170px;
   height: 150px;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;

   background-image: url('slice.png');
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: none;

   background-color: white;
}
```

Heres the div for it.

```
    <div class="coupon">
       <h1>Classic Combo</h1>
       <p>16" 1-Topping Pizza
          &amp; a 2-Liter of Your Choice
          For Only $14.99
       </p>
       <p>Expires 3/14</p>
   </div>
```

Yet the border is simply not appearing on my page. I tried looking it up, but the resolves for those problems havent worked for my problem.

Comment: In your CSS you're using an ID. In your HTML you're using a class. Change them to use the same selector.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.coupon`, not `#coupon`

`#` matches an id

`.` matches a class.

Comment: Ahh right. I mixed up wording between ID and class. However it seems the text size for paragraphs inside the border is not working properly. Not sure why.

Comment: @WillBro The size of the text inside the `<p>` tags looks okay to me in my test file.  What are you seeing, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Check you're classes and ID's

In CSS a class is defined with (.name)
an ID (#name)

Should clear up the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS ID selector contains a "#" immediately followed by the ID value, which must be an identifier
he following ID selector matches the H1 element whose ID attribute has the value "chapter1":

HTML

```
<h1 id="chapter1">Selector ID</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1#chapter1 { text-align: center }
```

A CSS Class selector contains a "." immediately followed by the Class value, which must be an identifier
he following Class selector matches the H1 element whose Class attribute has the value "chapter2":

HTML

```
<h1 class="chapter2">Selector Class</h1>
```

CSS

```
h1.chapter2 { text-align: center; color: red }
```